# Error Code 1 While Loading Python Pillow Module

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using python 3.6 64 bit. The python installation went down with no problem. But when I try to install pillow module using command prompt I get the "error 1". I googled It and couldn't find any explanations on this issue on windows. A youtube video shortly referred to it as "This issue is common if you're using windows 64bit your visual studio might not be up to date, but It's your problem." So I couldn't find a solution. Here are the screenshots of my command prompt.Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: "The python installation went down with no problem." The error message is telling you otherwise.

Comment: I thought I installed python correctly but having problem with pillow module. How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Make sure your Python install and build environment include zlib, just like it's asking for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with python actually It's my first time trying to use. I want to migrate to python. Can you explain what I should do in a detailed way?I don't know about the environment and zlib.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `-- disable-` with installation.
And add to disable all traceback errors that You see in console.
for example:
`pip install Pillow --disable-zlib` and so on. I`m not installed Pillow on Windows. You can try just to install Anaconda 3.